# Redirecting outgoing TCP connection from a process on Linux

Tags: c, linux, tcp

I have an C application that receives commands/info from a client application on localhost but needs to send data to the client on another IP address. Does someone have any previeous kind of experience of doing such a thing? From what i've read You cannot redirect an TCP connection?

Thanks

Comment: Looks like two separate connections - one with the local client, another with the remote client.

Comment: Could be managable via editing the routing table, as the incoming route could be different as the outgoing route.

Comment: But can this be done for only one user/process?